# How do I access values in a d3 json file with nested array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

Previously I was using a json file with the following format:

```
[{"lat":43.788458853157117,"lng":-79.282781549043008,"category":"volunteer","name":"Rita","url":"", "description":"xxx is a member of 13"},{"lat":43.7,"lng":-79.4,"category":"organization","name":"TCAN","url":"http://tcan.ca","description":"Lorem ipsum"}]
```

Now I am attempting to generate the json file from a Drupal site and am getting the following structure. How can I reference the lowest level fields. I have looked at examples using d3.net but have not found any that apply.

```
{
    "organizations": [
        {
            "member": {
                "field_category": "organization",
                "body": "A network of organizations in Toronto devoted to climate change mitigation and adaptation.",
                "URL": "xxx.ca",
                "title": "Toronto Climate Action Network",
                "field_lat": 43.7,
                "field_long": -79.4
            }
        },
        {
            "member": {
                "field_category": "abc",
                "body": "xxx.",
                "URL": "",
                "title": "yyy",
                "field_lat": 43.7,
                "field_long": -79.28
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your data is stored in the variable `data`:

```
var bottom = data.organizations.map(function(d) { return d.member; });
```

Comment: I am using the following code to access the json file -  how would this fit in? d3.json("d3_files/json/members4.json",function(error,data){
    circles.selectAll("circle")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
      .append("image")
   .attr("xlink:href", function(data) { 
        return lookupTable[data.category]();
 }) // end attr
 .attr("width", 64) // dimention of image
 .attr("height", 64)
    .attr("transform",function(data){
  return"translate("+projection([data.lng,data.lat])+")"
 }) // end transform attr

Comment: In particular how would I reference the "body" field?

Comment: You would use `bottom` instead of `data` in your D3 code after the conversion. To reference the `body` field, you can use something like `d3.selectAll("text").data(bottom).enter().append("text").text(function(d) { return d.body; })`.

Comment: Lars, many thanks. That really helped me and I got it to work. Clearly I am still missing some fundamentals.